# Can't seem to escape character from PHP date();

Tags: php, date, escaping

I'm trying to make date equal something like: Posted at 06:55 PM on 8/5/13. However I can't seem to get the "on" part work correctly. I've tried backslashing the characters I want, but everytime something like this happens: `06:55 PM o 8/5/13`
I can't seem to get the "n" to show up.

This is what I have:

```
date("h:i A \o\n m/d/y");
```

According to the php manual website this should work. Help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

PHP will interpret the `\n` as a newline character. To escape that, simply add an extra slash:

```
date("h:i A \o\\n m/d/y");
```

Outputs:

```
04:06 AM on 08/06/13
```

Live demo: http://codepad.org/oI6rIyTq

Answer (score 13):

You can also use single quotes to avoid escaping:

```
echo date('h:i A \o\n m/d/y');
```